# Function $g(x) = \lvert x\rvert$, $x \neq 0$: $g(0)$ not defined?

Tags: functions, absolute-value

I found this statement in topic limits:

> Consider the following function $g(x) = \lvert x\rvert$, $x \neq 0$. Observe that $g(0)$ is not defined.

How come $g(0)$ not defined when the absolute value function is defined at $0$?

Comment: The function $g$ is defined for all $x \neq 0$ and equals the absolute value where it is defined. The sentence does not say that the absolute value of $0$ is not defined.

Comment: $g $ is another function. you can define $h (x)=|x|$ and $h (0)=7$.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a perfectly valid and fundamental (albeit elementary) question about what it means to define a *function* (as opposed to giving an expression to implicitly define one without specifying its domain and codomain, which is unfortunately what many textbooks, teachers, or exercises do.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to define a function, you need three things:

1. a domain,
2. a codomain, and
3. a way of mapping things in the domain to things in the codomain.

In this case, $x=0$ is explicitly excluded from the domain of $g$, hence $g(0)$ is explicitly not defined.  That being said, there is *another* function, call it $f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x) = |x|$ which *is* defined at zero, and is equal to $g$ everywhere where both $f$ and $g$ are defined.  However, note that $f$ and $g$ are not the same function---they are different functions as they have different domains.

Moreover, as noted in the comments above, we could define yet another function $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by setting
$$ h(x) := \begin{cases} |x| & \text{if $x\ne 0$, and} \\
7 & \text{if $x=0$.} \\
\end{cases} $$
This function will have the same domain and codomain as $f$, but is a different function from $f$, as it maps the domain to the codomain differently (i.e. $f(0) = 0 \ne 7 = h(0)$).